# How to add clustering in mapbox in android if I am using SymbolManager to show my icons?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I want to perform clustering of symbols or icons or markers in mapbox in android and at the same time, I am performing click operation on the symbols that is why I am using symbol manager.

So I don't know how to add the click event to symbol layer in which clustering is possible or we can say that official documentation supports symbol layer for clustering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clusters can be queried: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/style/GeoJsonClusteringActivity.java#L121

Here's another example of clustering with `SymbolLayer`: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/

If needed, you can also use `queryRenderedFeatures()` to query a specific map layer: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=queryRenderedFeatures&unscoped_q=queryRenderedFeatures

Comment: Okay, so I want to ask that I am using SymbolManager to show my icons cause I want to handle the click event on the individual icon and I also want to cluster the icons. Problem is each clustering method involves SymbolLayer and I didn't use SymbolLayer, I used SymbolManager.

Comment: Cluster click support within the Annotation Plugin isn't finished yet https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/648

Comment: Is there any way to make symbols of symbol layer clickable or we can perform a certain task on clicking of the symbols of the symbol layer

Comment: yes,  use `queryRenderedFeatures()` to query a specific map layer and to see whether a `SymbolLayer` icon/`Feature` was clicked: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=queryRenderedFeatures&unscoped_q=queryRenderedFeatures